# What HTML tag can I use to store parent element data

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to insert a special element inside of a container div to store some information about an image that is located inside of the container. I know I can store the data in the container div data attributes itself or the image but I find it easier and cleaner when coming back later to projects to put them in their own DOM element. The data attributes are mainly for UI user actions like updating an element with jquery when a thumbnail is dragged into a droppable handle.

EXAMPLE:

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="thumbnail" src="/path/to/thumbnail" />
   <div data-imagefull="path/to/fullsize/image" data-imageid="179"></div>
</div>
```

In that example I would like to replace the div containing the data attr. with a different tag that is compliant with ie7 through to html5.

UPDATE :
Let me rephrase a bit. I like, and will continue to use the data attributes. I'ts the "div" tag alone that I would like to replace. There has to be a better tag than div since div is meant to display and I am not displaying anything. Just storing information.

Comment: Just put it into the `img` tag. It's the only logical way.

Comment: what's problem with data-* attributes ?

Comment: I updated my question since there was some confusion in the wording.

Comment: just put the data-* tags inside img, what's the hassle??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hidden](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute) attribute on your `div` tag:

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="thumbnail" src="/path/to/thumbnail" />
   <div data-imagefull="path/to/fullsize/image" data-imageid="179" hidden></div>
</div>
```

As stated in *spec*:

> User agents should not render elements that have the hidden attribute specified.

`hidden` attribute is HTML5's feature,so for supporting older browsers, you need this CSS also:

```
*[hidden] {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Interesting find... Especially this part in the w3c doc "While hiding the descriptions implies that they are not useful alone, they could be written in such a way that they are useful in the specific context of being referenced from the images that they describe."

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an element for this. Elements are for displaying information, not storing it.

The use case you describe is *exactly* what `data` attributes are designed for, and as such they should be placed on the `img` element they relate to.

Comment: There was some confusion in the wording of my question. I updated it to make myself more clear.

Comment: @TimJoyce Even with the update, having an element in the DOM solely for the purpose of storing information is incorrect. The answer regarding hidden `input` elements will work for you, but this method is semantically designed for usage within a form for submission via POST/GET.

Comment: but it's the easiest way when using a php loop to create the thumbnails. How else should I store the information that pertains to a specific thumbnail?

Comment: I assume the PHP loop is also creating the `img` element? If so, append the `data` attribute in that tag.

Comment: You seem adamant about keeping the data in the img tag it'self so that is what I will do. The question arose though, because I am using a custom thumbnail generator and the core php class doesn't accept parameters to add data attributes to the element. I was trying to avoid editing that php class.

Comment: @TimJoyce Being realistic, you can use whatever method works for you and is most productive. If editing the class takes you a couple of days it's probably not worth it. I was being adamant about usnig `data` attributes as it's definitely the best practice in this situation and it's always best to try and guide along that path :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use it like this:

```
<img id="geoff" data-geoff="geoff de geoff" src="image.jpg" />
```

Get it in JS using:

```
var geoff = document.getElementById("geoff");
alert(geoff.getAttribute("data-geoff"));
```

You can add any number of data attributes to the tag.

And this works in ie6 and ie7 also.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that:

- Use for each piece of data own DOM element (any you like) with `hidden` attribute or `style="display: none;"`
- Use some DOM element with JSON data inside, e.g. `<span style="display: none;">{"id": 1, "name":"John"}</span>`

If you ask me, I would suggest to use `data-` attribute or `<input type="hidden" value="somevalue" />`. But the last variant (input) supposed to live inside of forms.

I think additionally you can invent few more ways of how to store data. But do you really need to reinvent wheel?

---

- [HTML hidden Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp)
- [Style display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)

Answer (score 0):

just put the data-* tags inside img, what's the hassle??
a lot of responsive pictures plugins infact utilise stuff like

```
<img src="lo-fi.png" data-src481="medium.png" data-src1025="hi-fi.png" alt="example" />
```